# BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert multiple records to MongoDB at once , so for this i created a javaBean for each record to be inserted and added them to ArrayList .

And finally from the ArrayList , i am trying to perform a insert operation as shown below

```
public void insert(ArrayList<QuoteReportBean> quotelist) {
     BasicDBList totalrecords = new BasicDBList();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int valuecount=0;
     for (QuoteReportBean reportbean: quotelist) {
         valuecount++;
            BasicDBObject dbrecord = new BasicDBObject();
            dbrecord.append("cust_id", reportbean.getCustomerId());
            dbrecord.append("unique_symbol", reportbean.getUniqueSymbol());
            sb.append(reportbean.getUniqueSymbol()+",");
            dbrecord.append("exch", reportbean.getExchange());
            dbrecord.append("access_time", reportbean.getDate());
            totalrecords.add(dbrecord);
          }
     WriteResult result = coll.insert(totalrecords,WriteConcern.NORMAL);
}
```

But i am the follwoing error

```
Exception in thread "taskExecutor-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]
        at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:159)
        at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:150)
        at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList.get(BasicBSONList.java:104)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.apply(DBCollection.java:501)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.apply(DBCollection.java:491)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:195)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:180)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:58)
```

**Could anybody please help me  as how to resolve this ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BasicDBList can't be used to do inserts of multiple documents, it's only used for arrays inside a single document.  To do a bulk insert, you need to pass an array of DBObjects into the insert method instead.

I changed your code to do this, and it worked without error:

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int valuecount = 0;
    final QuoteReportBean[] quotelist = {new QuoteReportBean()};
    DBObject[] totalrecords = new BasicDBObject[quotelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < quotelist.length; i++) {
        QuoteReportBean reportbean = quotelist[i];
        valuecount++;
        BasicDBObject dbrecord = new BasicDBObject();
        dbrecord.append("cust_id", reportbean.getCustomerId());
        dbrecord.append("unique_symbol", reportbean.getUniqueSymbol());
        sb.append(reportbean.getUniqueSymbol() + ",");
        dbrecord.append("exch", reportbean.getExchange());
        dbrecord.append("access_time", reportbean.getDate());
        totalrecords[i] = dbrecord;
    }
    WriteResult result = coll.insert(totalrecords, WriteConcern.NORMAL);
```