# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]

Tags: scala, casbah

After another SO poster(Vinicius Miana) resolved my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057695/no-implicit-view-available) to insert a `List[DBObject]` ...

```
// Bulk insert all documents
collection.insert(MongoDBList(docs)) // docs is List[DBObject]
```

Now, I'm seeing this error when trying to insert.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]`

**EDIT**

Full stack trace

```
[info]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]
[info]   at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:161)
[info]   at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:152)
[info]   at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList.get(BasicBSONList.java:104)
[info]   at com.mongodb.DBCollection.apply(DBCollection.java:767)
[info]   at com.mongodb.DBCollection.apply(DBCollection.java:756)
[info]   at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:220)
[info]   at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:204)
[info]   at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:76)
[info]   at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollectionBase$class.insert(MongoCollection.scala:508)
[info]   at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection.insert(MongoCollection.scala:866)
```

I've checked out a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150272/basicbsonlist-can-only-work-with-numeric-keys-not-id) with my exact same problem, but I'm not sure how to apply the accepted answer.

Does this error mean that I cannot insert any key-value pairs such that `value` is not castable to `Int` (per [BasicBSONList](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/types/BasicBSONList.html))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoDBList` is not the same as an ordinary list, it is a convenience wrapper for `BasicDBList` and as such converting to vargs doesn't work as expected.

You should supply `List[DBObject]` and then explode into vargs:

```
val docs = List[DBObject("a" -> "b")
collection.insert(docs: _*)
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't insert a `MongoDBList` into a collection. If you want to insert multiple documents in a single operation, you just need to pass your `List[DBObject]` directly to `insert` method:

```
collection.insert(docs: _*)
```

The `_*` is needed because `insert` is a varargs method.

On the other side I have to admit that this exception is quite confusing here and its error message doesn't have too much to do with the actual problem. I suspect it happens because Casbah tries to treat `MongoDBList` as a regular document that can be inserted into database. It attempts to access the `_id` of the object that it tries to insert and that causes the exception.

Comment: I get the same error when using collection.insert(docs: _*). Also, looking at the source (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/types/BasicBSONList.java), I'm confused why `_id` is trying to be parsed as an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Salat author here.  Ghik is correct: your problem is that you are wrapping your model objects in a spurious `MongoDBList`.  Also, you appear to be feeding model objects directly to your collection.  If you're going to do that, you need to manually serialize each object before inserting it.

I would recommend this approach is unnecessary!  Here's what you need to do.  Get either `SalatDAO` or `ModelCompanion` working - see https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/SalatDAO and https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/SalatWithPlay2.

Here's a sample implementation of `SalatDAO` for a model object called `MyObject`:

```
object MyObjectDAO extends SalatDAO[MyObject, ObjectId](collection = MongoConnection()("my_test_db")("my_test_coll"))
```

Then just insert your docs using `SalatDAO#insert(docs: Traversable[ObjectType], wc: WriteConcern = defaultWriteConcern)`

```
MyObjectDAO.insert(docs)
```